# Issues with URL rewriting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to create an online system to read a magazine's pages, so I created two scaffolds (one for the magazine itself, the other, nested, for the pages). Everything is working fine, but the url appears like the following:

`domain.com/magazines/<magazine title>/pages/2/`

I tried make the URL look more like `/<magazine title>/<page number>` by simply removing the page's class name from the URL, which didn't work

Here is my router.rb file:

```
  root to: 'home#index'
  resources :magazines do
    resources :pages, except: [:index, :edit, :new]
    get '/:id' => 'pages#show', :as => 'custom'
  end
```

But when I add a link_to "custom_path", I get `undefined local variable or method 'custom_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000010bb1e70>:0x00000010bb0d18>`

I know I did something wrong, but where?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Run rake routes so you can get the correct path names. Then again, if you want `pages#show`, it's already in resources list.